# which is not functionally dependent on columns in group by clause this is incompatible with sql_modeonly_full_group

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1055

```
select countrycode,name, max(population) 
from city 
group by CountryCode LIMIT 0, 1000
```

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'world.city.Name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by  0.000 sec

Help me out with this problem.

Comment: Error message says column `name` not in group by clause and not an aggregate. You can't do that. Put name into group by clause.

Comment: The old GROUP BY rule says: GROUP BY all columns you SELECT - except those who are arguments to set functions. (And you'll never go wrong.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says you need for all columns in the select a [aggregation functio](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)n or they have to be in the  `GROUP BY`

in your case put it also in the `GROUP BY`

```
select countrycode,name, max(population) 
from city 
group by CountryCode,name LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Comment: Or... use `MAX(name)` in the select list.

Comment: every country has only one name so it will not need a max

Comment: I would conceptually agree if `country_code` is a PK. However, MySQL does not implement functional dependency, so `MAX()` or `GROUP BY` is needed. This would not be needed in PostgreSQL that does implement it.

Comment: yes  linked in my answer to  the aggregation function, which lead to even more information and i explained the full group by, i think that should explain everything there is to know

Comment: @TheImpaler Both MySQL and PostgreSQL can infer functional dependencies, but neither can make that inference if the grouping is on a non-unique column.

Comment: @BillKarwin I stand corrected. I didn't know MySQL had implemented functional dependencies.

Comment: It was implemented in MySQL 5.7.5 released 2014-09-25. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: I was curious, so I looked up when PostgreSQL implemented detection of functional dependencies for ungrouped columns. It was in in version 9.1, in 2011.